# How to set pgtype.Null as a default when querying a null field?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I am handling postgresql db with Gorm in Golang. And I'm using the pgtype package to handle nullable fields.
To insert a null value into a field, I have to set the status to pgtype.null as follows.

```
type Person struct {
  ID string
  Age int
  Nickname pgtype.Text
}

func CreatePerson(){
  john := &Person{
    ID: "John",
    Age: 30,
    Nickname: pgtype.Text{Status: pgtype.Null},
  }
  DB.Create(john) // ID: John, Age: 30, Nickname: NULL
}
```

However, When I load the data from the DB, the null field will be converted to Zero value for pgtypte.Text, that is, its status is Undefined.

```
func GetPerson(){
  john := &Person{}
  DB.Where("id = ?", "John").First(john) // ID: John, Nickname: NUL

  /* john = {
    ID: "John",
    Age: 30,
    Nickname: pgtype.Text{Status: pgtype.Undefined},
  }
  */
}
```

Here, it is unnatural that the gorm struct that used to save in the DB is different from the gorm struct loaded from the DB.

Also, when I modify some of the fields of the struct and save it again, an error occurs due to the status of undefined.

```
func GetAndSave(){
  john := &Person{}
  DB.Where("id = ?", "John").First(john) // ID: John, Nickname: NUL

  /* john = {
    ID: "John",
    Age: 30,
    Nickname: pgtype.Text{Status: pgtype.Undefined},
  }
  */
  john.Age = 31
  DB.Select("*").Update(john) // Error since its nickname has undefined status
}
```

Therefore, I want to make pgtype fields automatically have null status for null fields when I load data with the null field from the db. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [BeforeCreate](https://gorm.io/docs/hooks.html) hook to set the default value for fields.

try

```
func (person *Person) BeforeCreate(_ *gorm.DB) error {
    if person.Nickname.Status == pgtype.Undefined {
        person.Nickname.Status = pgtype.Null
    }
    return nil
}
```

This will check the pgtype field is `Undefined` and set that as `Null` for `Person` struct before creating the entry in the database. And you will be able to omit the `Nickname` field while creating

```
john := &Person{
    ID:  "John",
    Age: 30,
}
DB.Create(john) // ID: John, Age: 30, Nickname: NULL
```

Same way, you can use `AfterFind` hook to update  the resulting response fields

```
func (person *Person) AfterFind(_ *gorm.DB) error {
    if person.Nickname.Status == pgtype.Undefined {
        person.Nickname.Status = pgtype.Null
    }
    return nil
}
```

Hope this helps